# How to create FTP connection in UWP?

Tags: c#, ftp, win-universal-app, universal

I would like to write a simple FTP client UWP program, but when i create the WebResponse it throws an exception:

> Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed.

```
private async void ListDirectory()
    {
        var obj = App.Current as App;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(obj.ServerUri);
        if (obj.credential != null)
        {
            request.Credentials = obj.credential;
        }

        request.Method = "LIST";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) // the exception is here
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string item = reader.ReadLine();
                    // add to list etc...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I searched after this on the internet and I found that I have to enable the SSL, but I couldn't find this option in the Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Try using FtpWebRequest if that's available in UWP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Chilkat FTP component](http://www.example-code.com/csharp_winrt/ftp_asyncUpload.asp) or WinRT sample: [Windows 8.1 Sockets: Ftp Client Sample with Sockets in C#/Xaml](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-SocketsFtp-4fc23b33/view/Discussions)

Comment: In case someone is stumbling about this: Try https://github.com/kiewic/FtpClient which finally helped me for Windows 10.

(If you cannot open the project in your VS, just take the two relevant classes from it.)